# Strange ghost object behavior in rails/redis app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to create a simple settings object for a RoR application. I want just a single instance of the object class and I want it to be able to read/write to a redis database. Most importantly, it should always be up-to-date with the database. Since this app is running on web dynos on heroku I was worried that each dyno would contain it's own copy of the object, so I added a redis pubsub setup to notify all instances that the db had been updated and to reload the data. That all seems to work just fine - data is saved, all the instances get the message and update themselves, etc.

However, when loading the data into the view I'm sometimes presented with stale data and I can't figure out where this data is coming from.

Steps to show problem:

1. Load the page and see the correct (db sync'd) data
2. Refresh the page repeatedly and see the data stays the same
3. Update the data and post back to the database
4. Verify the data is correct in the db
5. Verify that any running instance objects receive the update message and print `#value-updated: OK`
6. Verify that any running instance objects contain the correct data
7. Refresh the view repeatedly until the stale data shows up again

I have checked that it isn't a caching issue with the view by verifying that the controller is loading the stale data from an out-of-sync object that lives... somewhere. Also, there is only ever a single out-of-sync object, no matter how many times I update the data, and it always shows the data as it was in the db when the app initially starts up.

Below is a simplified version of the code I'm using. Any pointers from rails gurus would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. - I seem to be unable to replicate this locally. It only happens when I push to one of my heroku environments.

**MyObject class:**

```
class MyObject
    def self.instance_of
        @object ||= new
    end

    def initialize
        refresh
    end

    def my_value=(value)
        @my_value = value
    end

    def my_value
        @my_value
    end

    def save
        response = $redis.set("my_value", @my_value)
        $redis.publish "value-updated", response
    end

    def refresh
        @my_value = $redis.get("my_value") 
    end
end
```

**Sub listener in initializer:**

```
Thread.new
    $redis.subscribe("value-updated") do |on|
      on.message do |channel, msg|
        puts "##{channel} : #{msg]}"
      end
    end
end
```

**In the Controller:**

```
@my_value = MyObject.instance_of.my_value
```

**In the View:**

```
<input type="text" value="<%= @my_value %>" />
```